# Windows 2008 Server R2 Command Prompt/Power Shell Slow Scrolling

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, command-line-interface

I'm having an issue with various Windows 2008 Server R2 machines scrolling very slowly using the command line or Power Shell. For instance, if I type "dir", I see my contents being displayed 1 line at a time at about 1 second intervals. How can this be corrected?

Comment: Does it take a long time with `dir |Out-Null` (pipeline will exit without output) or is it equally slow ?

Comment: Using |Out-Null seems to work quickly.

Answer (score 4):

Scrolling in console windows is notoriously bad with a generic SVGA video driver. Assuming you're using the machines' main video output I suspect that's your issue.